# MacBook VPN connection disconnects after two minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, vpn

My MacBook Pro's VPN disconnects two minutes after it connects. I change the account and I had no luck with it, Any ideas?

Comment: When it connects do you get an active connection to your internal resources?

Comment: Anything in the system log? Open Console in the Utilities directory. Select FILES, system.log in the left pane, and type 'pppd' in the search box.  The right pane will show the log messages for VPN connections.

Comment: @hobs : yes, I have an active connection.

Comment: I would try also to connect via a third-party vpn app, to see its behavior. [Viscosity](http://www.thesparklabs.com/viscosity/) is my favorite. Although it costs $9, it has a 30 days trial so you can see if it works.

Comment: Do you have access to the vpn endpoint logs? That should be a good starting point.

Comment: What is the software running on the VPN server you're connected to?

Answer (score 2):

Under the built-in client, this is solved by:

setting the following on the VPN custom connection:

a) "lifetime time 24 hours;" or more
b) dpd_delay 0;
c) proposal_check claim;

This can be done by creating a file, e.g. `/etc/racoon/fix.1.1.conf` and adding the lines above in there.  Also ensure that the line "include /etc/racoon/*.conf" is not commented out in `/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`.

Comment: It's been a while, but where is this "VPN custom connection" on OSX?  Or does one set it in a config file from the command prompt?  If so, in which file?

Comment: @Lifeboy I'll have a look when I get home. My answer may have been helpful at the time, but now I can't remember? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯